# Index.php для всех, и куки бы для всех.

Tags: .htaccess, cookie

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Этот код, что нарыл я на просторах инета, перенаправляет site.ru/21/22 на site.ru/index.php. И при этом не перенаправляет css, js, jpg обращения. Все отлично, но как сделать, чтобы он перенаправлял еще и куки куда-то в одно место, а то в итоге site.ru/21/22 и site.ru/21/23 имеют разные куки. :(

```
$.cookie('login',login,'/');
```

Пробовал указывать путь для куки, и вроде бы все заработало, но сегодня по неизвесным для меня причинам опять сломалось, и в отчаянии я решил обратиться к сообществу. Честно пробовал курить мануал, но толку это не принесло. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что ж, друзья. Ответов нет, и я не удивлен, так как все опять само заработало. Путь к кукам решил ставить потому как была проблема с адресами у них, и сначала помогло, а потом опять сломалось. Теперь убрал пути у кук, и все опять заработало как надо)))
Как говорил электрик на заводе "Электричество наукой до конца не изучено".
В общем всем спасибо. До свидания.